# Spring HTTP binding factory issue with CXF

Tags: web-services, spring, cxf

I am getting an exception regarding binding factory for HTTP when trying to invoke a web service using CXF generated client. The client code is:

```
private final static QName SERVICE = new QName("http://com.myAppService.service", "myService");
        try {
            wsdlURL = new URL("http://myAppservice.com/services/myService?wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception (THIS_METHOD + ex.getMessage() ); 
        }

        try{
             service = new MyAppService(wsdlURL, SERVICE);
             port = service.getMyServiceHttpport();
```

The exception I see on the console is:

```
[2/18/13 4:27:00:295 PST] 00000609 SystemErr     R Caused by: org.apache.cxf.BusException: No binding factory for namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/ registered.
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.BindingFactoryManagerImpl.getBindingFactory(BindingFactoryManagerImpl.java:91)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:114)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:52)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:102)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:115)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.createPort(ServiceImpl.java:434)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:312)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:299)
        at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:40)
        at com.cisco.myAppService.service.MyService.getMyServiceHttpport(MyService.java:129)
```

Any idea how can I bind the HTTP port. The header of my wsdl is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:impl="http://com.cisco.ipcentral.service" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" targetNamespace="http://com.cisco.ipcentral.service">
    <wsdl:documentation>MyService</wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://com.myAppService.service">
```